# How do I change my interface language on Transifex?

Tags: user-interface, transifex

[Transifex](http://transifex.com) allows users to translate strings on the platform, and there is a [dedicated project](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/transifex/) just for translating the platform itself. However, I don't seem to have access to any functionality to change my interface language on Transifex, any idea on how to change it to a language other than English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find a dropdown menu on the bottom left of each page where you can change the interface language. It's to the right of the copyright message.

Hope that helps!

Sam @Transifex

Comment: Opps, didn't actually notice that button at the bottom. Is it possible to make it more prominent or put it in the Account Settings page?

Comment: Hmm that's a good suggestion. I'll pass it along to our designer and see what he does. Thanks!